# Laravel. conflict with routes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problemwith my routes. When I call 'editPolicy' I dont know what execute but is not method editPolicy. I think I have got problem beteweeb this two routes:

### My web.php ##

```
       Route::get('admin/edit/{user_id}', 'PolicyController@listPolicy')->name('listPolicy');

       Route::put('/admin/edit/{policy_id}','PolicyController@editPolicy')->name('editPolicy');
```

I call listPolicy route in all.blade.php view like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('listPolicy', $user->id) }}">{{ $user->name }}</a>
```

And call editPolicy route in edit.blade.php view like this:

```
   <a href="{{ route('editPolicy', $policy->id) }}" title="Remove" class="text-danger">Remove</a></td>
```

My PolicyController.php is:

```
    public function listPolicy($user_id)
    { 
     $policies = Policy::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
     return view('admin/edit',compact('policies'));
    }

     public function editPolicy($policy_id)
     {
      dd($policy_id);
     }
```

But I dont know what happend when I call editPolicy route but editPolicy method not executing.

Any help please?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking an anchor will always trigger a GET request.
`route('listPolicy', $user->id)` and `route('editPolicy', $policy->id)` will both return `admin/edit/{an_id}` so when you click your anchor, `listPolicy` will be executed. If you want to call `editPolicy`, you have to send a PUT request via a form, as defined when you declared your route with `Route::put`.

Quick note, your two routes have the same URL but seem to do very different things, you should differentiate them to avoid disarray. It's ok to have multiple routes with the same url if they have an impact on the same resource and different methods. For example for showing, deleting or updating the same resource.
Have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing).

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing the call:                             
`<a href="{{ route('editPolicy', $policy->id) }}" method="PUT" title="Remove" class="text-danger">Remove</a>` Not erros but not call method editPolicy

Comment: PUT methods are meant to update a resource on the server. You can't define the method for an anchor, it will always be GET. Have a look at the [methods definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

If you want `editPolicy` to be a GET method, you have to declare it as GET and not PUT, and use a different URL than `listPolicy`.

Comment: Solution maybe is renaming the route? ¨´Route::get('/admin/edit_policy/{policy_id}','PolicyController@editPolicy')->name('editPolicy')´